# Can some decrypt this line of code before I go mucking my machine

Tags: perl, decode

Here is the line

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's/\x00\x85\xc0\x74\x7b\xe8/\x00\x85\xc0\xEB\x7b\xe8/g'
```

Just wondering what the string outputs to.

Comment: It replaces bytes in the file you forgot to provide.

Comment: I "forgot" to provide it because I didn't want to reveal the file it was trying to replace! 

Comment: Yet there's no way to know what those bytes mean without context.

Comment: @DiBobble so, did the – um – "file" work as desired in the end?

Answer (score 3):

`s/…/…/g` is the global substitute command. It replaces the matched text (the first part between `/…/` with the replacement (the second `/…/`), i.e. `s/pattern/replace/g`. `/g` means it applies to all matches in a single line.

Therefore, `s/\x00\x85\xc0\x74\x7b\xe8/\x00\x85\xc0\xEB\x7b\xe8/g` will replace all occurrences of `\x00\x85\xc0\x74\x7b\xe8` with `\x00\x85\xc0\xEB\x7b\xe8` (in every line).

`\xNN` is the hexadecimal representation of a single byte. Most of the bytes in your question are non-printable ASCII characters:

```
\x00\x85\xc0\x74\x7b\xe8
              t   {      
\x00\x85\xc0\xEB\x7b\xe8
                  {
```

As you can see, only `\x74` (`t`) and `\x7b` (`{`) are in the printable character range.

`-p` will apply your statement to every line in the input file. `-i` will edit the input file in-place. `-e` specifies the perl code to execute.

So for your invocation to be correct, you must actually pass a file:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\x00\x85\xc0\x74\x7b\xe8/\x00\x85\xc0\xEB\x7b\xe8/g' yourfilehere
```